# Find the area portion of Surface of $x^2+y^2+z^2 =b^2$ inside a cylinder

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

Find the area of the surface portion: $x^2+y^2+z^2=b^2$ that remains within the right cylinder $ x^2+y^2=by$ , where  $b > 0$

Comment: It is that the sphere is centered at the origin and the cylinder will always be located on the positive Y axis, as shown to accommodate the equation of the cylinder and are thus:  $ x^2+(y-b/2)^2=(b/2)^2$ , Where   $(0,b/2)$ is the center of the cylinder.

Comment: But my problem is that I can not define the boundaries for the surface integral. I have done the following parametrization $r(x,y)=<x,y,f(x,y)>$ where $f(x,y)= z= \sqrt {b^2 -x^2 -y^2}$